# Return the nodes of a tree represented by a list, recursively in Python

Tags: python, recursion, tree

I have to create a list who contains number of a binary tree in ascending order. But I have some difficulties to do it. Moreover, I must do it using recursion!

Here is an example of my binary dtree:

```
t1 = [[[None,4,None],5,[None,5,None]],6,[None,7,[None,8,None]]]
```

and my function returns:

```
[2, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

What I did for the moment:

```
def recursive_course(t):
    """  Return  list which contain the numbers of t in order from a binary tree - recursive"""
    liste=[]
    for i in t:
        if isinstance(i,int):
            liste.append(i)
        if isinstance(i,list):
            for j in i:
                if isinstance(j,int):
                    liste.append(j)
                if isinstance(j,list):
                    for h in j:
                        if isinstance(h,int):
                            liste.append(h)
    if t != None:
        liste.append(t[1])
    return liste
```

It works, but not totally.

I'll explain what I mean:
With my example, my function works but the problem is that when I add a subtree, my function doesn't work because I need as many trees as there are loops "for". That's why I must use a recursive method but I don't know how I could do this with my code above.

Comment: What is your function *supposed* to return given that input? The output you are getting includes `2`, which is not in your original list, which is pretty confusing.

Comment: Is this your classmate perhaps? Very similar (possibly duplicate) question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64982694/insert-a-new-value-in-a-tree-python

Comment: euh I don't know but maybe, it is probably last question of our project

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is a functional heritage and so using it with functional style yields the best results. Because the binary tree can be nested to any depth, you cannot rely upon a fixed number of nested `for` loops. This is no problem however because functional style uses recursion to loop, not `for` statements.

Let's start by writing some basic functions for our binary tree module, `btree`. Defining functions like `is_empty`, `left`, `right`, and `value` makes it easy for us to know simple things about our tree and work with them using meaningful identifiers -

```py
# btree.py

def is_empty (t):
  return not t

def left (t):
  if is_empty(t):
    raise RuntimeError("cannot access left of empty tree")
  else:
    return t[0]

def right (t):
  if is_empty(t):
    raise RuntimeError("cannot access right of empty tree")
  else:
    return t[2]

def value (t):
  if is_empty(t):
    raise RuntimeError("cannot access value of empty tree")
  else:
    return t[1]
```

Now we want to define `inorder` which will traverse our tree's nodes in order. First visiting the `left` (smallest) node, working to the `right` (largest) node -

```
# btree.py (continued)

def inorder (t):
  if is_empty(t):
    return
  else:
    yield from inorder(left(t))  # recursion
    yield value(t)
    yield from inorder(right(t)) # recursion
```

We can write our `main` program now, using our new binary tree -

```py
# main.py

from btree import inorder

t1 = [[[None,4,None],5,[None,5,None]],6,[None,7,[None,8,None]]]

print(list(inorder(t1)))
```

```
[4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , I didn't see it !!

Comment: Could you explain me your last function def inorder(t) ?   I never used "yield"  I always use list.   Is it possible to transform your yield in list ?

Comment: sure, `if is_empty(t): return []` and `else: return inorder(left(t)) + [value(t)] + inorder(right(t))`. You can also use `else: return [*inorder(left(t)), value(t), *inorder(right(t))]` which does the same thing. Then in the final print, you can change `print(list(inorder(t1)))` to `print(inorder(t1))`.